# Getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE back from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, go

I am using an ajax call to call a method from my server side code which is written in GOlang, The server side code calls an API and then I want it to return the response back to the front end. However I keep getting the `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error. For extra information, I am calling the Postman Api to create a collection. The issue seems to be that it is not returning any information but im not sure why?

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/createCollection",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        timeout : 300000,
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(data) {    
            let json = JSON.parse(data)
            let response = JSON.parse(json)
            //do something with response
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + xhr.statusText)
        },
    });
```

**Golang:**

```
r.HandleFunc("/createCollection", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error reading body: %v", err)
            http.Error(w, "can't read body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        }


        var data postmanBody
        if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("failed to unmarshal:", err)
        }

        project, err := loader.LoadProjectFromConfigFile(projectConfigFile, projectSubViewName)


        response := apiController.CreateJsonThenCallApi(data.XApiKey, data.Environment, project) //Calls the postman Api
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(string(response))
    })
```

Comment: Not enough information here. Have you verified that `CreateJsonThenCallApi ` is returning a response? Your handler seems to be correct if I ignore the `CreateJsonThenCallApi` part

Comment: Yes it 100% returns a response, I get the error exactly after it is returned

Comment: @bradleyplater why check for errors when you ultimately ignore them and continue as if nothing happened?

Comment: @bradleyplater update your question by adding the definition of `postmanBody`, and the implementations of `LoadProjectFromConfigFile` and `CreateJsonThenCallApi`. Also you're not handling the error returned from the project-loading method call, fix that, re-test, and if you still get the same behaviour update the question with the new code so that we do not waste time on things that do not cause the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @mkopriva The above is the minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue, In my error section I do have some code which handles the error but that isn't important to this thread

Comment: @bradleyplater not sure this is related but your js seems to expect json, while your server returns `application/text` (which is not a valid mime type btw)

Comment: @mkopriva I have updated the code to what I have currently tried as I noticed the issue above too

Comment: If `response` is a slice of bytes that already contains json you do not want to pass that to `Encode` or `json.Marshal`, unless you're aware of what that results in and is exactly what you want.